# filter children kendo menu asp mvc

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have a little problem and i don't know how to solve, i want to filter the children of my menu or return only one value of the children menu, i have this in my controller:

```
 public ActionResult ModelBinding()
    {
        NorthwindDataContext northwind = new NorthwindDataContext();
        var data = (from m in northwind.Categories
                    join a in northwind.Products on m.CategoryID equals a.CategoryID
                    where m.CategoryID == 1 && a.ProductID == 1 
                    select m).ToList();
        return View(data);
    }
```

and this is my view

```
 @model IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Category>
 @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
      .Name("Menu")
      .BindTo(Model, mappings => 
      {
            mappings.For<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Category>(binding => binding
                    .ItemDataBound((item, category) =>
                    {
                        item.Text = category.CategoryName;
                    })
                    .Children(category => category.Products));
            mappings.For<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Product>(binding => binding
                    .ItemDataBound((item, product) =>
                    {
                        item.Text = product.ProductName;
                    }));
      })
)
```

in my controller i send the filter where ProductID == 1 but when menu run this, the category return me all products of that category, sometime like this

- Beberages
  - Chai
  - Chang
  - Guarana Fantastica
  - Sasquach Ale

and i want that only return me one product, so how i can do it that or where i can to put the filter, someone to have one example i really appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: Please check my answer below and inform if it is working...

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at my answer on [Multiple filters in Kendo Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240277/multiple-filters-in-kendo-combobox/29251880#29251880). In that page, I shown filtering on Kendo Combobox. Hope this helps...